# Comparison of fixnum with nil failed, value not nil

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm writing a program that takes an array and the index of a value within it and then finds the closest number that is larger (if a tie left side has precedence). However, I cannot seem to debug part of my program as my logic and even the output seem to have value but, when it runs it gives an error that Fixnum can not be compared with nil and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
    i = idx
    until  arr[i] > arr[idx] || i == 0
        i -=1
    end
    left = arr[i]
    lefti = i
    i = idx
    puts arr[idx] #4
    puts arr[i] #4 (functions as nil in next line)
    until (arr[idx] < arr[i]) || (i == arr.length)
        i += 1
    end
    right = arr[i]
    righti = i
    puts righti
    if  righti == arr.length && lefti == 0
        return nil
    elsif right == left
        return lefti
    elsif right < left
        return lefti
    elsif right > left
        return righti
    else
        print "idk man"
    end
end

nearest_larger([2,8,4,3], 2)
```

--Error message--

comparison of Fixnum with nil failed

(repl):11:in `<'

(repl):11:in `nearest_larger'

(repl):30:in `initialize'

Comment: Hi - the full error message/stacktrace would be really helpful here. Usually the stacktrace gives the line number of the line of your code that is causing the error. The stacktrace will be 20-30 lines of filenames... if you aren't getting it, then run your program with --trace

Comment: for now i'm just entering the code in on repl.it but i will include the error message @TarynEast

Comment: ok, so it's this line that's failing: `until (arr[idx] < arr[i]) || (i == arr.length)` which means `arr[i]` is nil... which means something is going wrong in the first few lines of your code. I'd recommend putting in some more puts statements at the very top to see what you get for `i` and `arr[i]` before you get to line 11

Comment: also `(i == arr.length)`  are you aware that length and the last item will be different? ie for an array of size three: `[a,b,c]` the length will be 3, but `c == arr[2]` not `arr[3]` ? This is important... because you might be going one beyond the edge of the array (and you need to check if that's the case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when it runs it gives an error that Fixnum can not be compared with nil and I have no idea why

It's because of this expression:

```
until (arr[idx] < arr[i]) || (i == arr.length)
```

Ruby evaluates it from left to right, i.e.:

```
arr = [2, 8, 4, 3]
idx = 2
i   = 4

until (arr[idx] < arr[i]) || (i == arr.length)
#      arr[ 2 ] < arr[4]
#             4 < nil
#          ArgumentError
```

You can fix it by exchanging both checks:

```
until (i == arr.length) || (arr[idx] < arr[i])
#      4 == 4
#       true
```

Ruby doesn't evaluate the right hand side because of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

---

You're not asking for a different approach, but I couldn't resist to find a more compact solution. Here's my attempt:

We have to compare the value at the starting index `n` with its adjacent values, i.e.

- compare `array[n]` to `array[n - 1]`
- compare `array[n]` to `array[n + 1]`
- compare `array[n]` to `array[n - 2]`
- compare `array[n]` to `array[n + 2]`
- ...

I would start by writing a method that returns the array of adjacent indices in alternating order, starting at `n`, i.e. `[n - 1, n + 1, n - 2, n + 2, ...]`:

```
def adjacent_indices(size, n)
  (1...size).flat_map { |i| [n - i, n + i] }.reject { |i| i < 0 || i >= size }
end
```

[`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) returns the aforementioned array. [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-reject) is a bounds check, it removes all indices that are below `0` or above the array's `size`.

Example:

```
adjacent_indices(5, 0) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
adjacent_indices(5, 1) #=> [0, 2, 3, 4]
adjacent_indices(5, 2) #=> [1, 3, 0, 4]
adjacent_indices(5, 3) #=> [2, 4, 1, 0]
adjacent_indices(5, 4) #=> [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

That looks good.

Using [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), we can easily find the first index `i` whose array value (i.e. `array[i]`) is larger than the value at index `n` (i.e. `array[n]`):

```
def nearest_larger(array, n)
  adjacent_indices(array.size, n).find { |i| array[i] > array[n] }
end
```

Example:

```
#    0  1  2  3
a = [2, 8, 4, 3]
nearest_larger(a, 0) #=> 1
nearest_larger(a, 1) #=> nil
nearest_larger(a, 2) #=> 1
nearest_larger(a, 3) #=> 2
```

Comment: The solution works great, thank you! However if seems I'm still not fully grasping the concept behind my error... if I set i = idx before the code ran should both idx and i not equal 2?

Comment: Very nice, Stefan. Another way to calculate `adjacent_indices`: `(1...size).each_with_object([]) { |i,a| a<<n-i if i<=n; a<<n+i if n+i<size }`.

Comment: @Chris `i = idx` sets the initial value for `i`, but you're incrementing `i` within the loop and eventually `ary[i]` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Amit has answered your question, I'd like to show you one way (among many, many) you could make your method more Ruby-like, which in part means relying less on indices. I'll explain this with an example.

```
arr = [2, 8, 4, 7, 3, 8, 5, 9]
idx = 3
```

As you see, we want the closest larger value to:

```
target = arr[3]
  #=> 7
```

The answer is `8`. Let's find the index of the closest higher value (which of course gives you that value).

The answer I will give is not the best way of doing it, but I've chosen it because, by stepping through it in detail, you will learn much about Ruby generally.

Often when a question involves indices, the first thing you will do is write:

```
arr.each_with_index
  # => #<Enumerator: [2, 8, 4, 7, 3, 8, 5, 9]:each_with_index>
```

For this discussion, lets assign this enumerator to a variable:

```
enum = arr.each_with_index
```

As you see, `enum` is an enumerator, meaning it is an instance of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html).

We can convert this enumerator to an array as follows:

```
pairs = enum.to_a
  #=> [[2, 0], [8, 1], [4, 2], [7, 3], [3, 4], [8, 5], [5, 6], [9, 7]]
```

But wait, the class `Enumerator` does not have a method `:to_a`. That means that it is being inherited from one of `Enumerator`'s ancestors, which are:

```
Enumerator.ancestors
  #=> [Enumerator, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

We could look through these (in order) for `:to_a`, but a more direct way is:

```
enum.method(:to_a).owner
  #=> Enumerable
```

Sure enough, it is [Enumerator#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

That was a bit of diversion, but now let's work with the array `pairs` above. Incidentally, you would normally write just:

```
pairs = arr.each_with_index.to_a
```

rather than having an intermediate variable like `enum`.

The beauty of `pairs` is that by manipulating its elements (two-element arrays), the index of each element of `arr` is carried along with the element itself.

Try this:

```
before = (idx.zero? ? [] : pairs[0..idx-1]).reverse
  #=> [[4, 2], [8, 1], [2, 0]] 
after  = pairs[idx+1..-1]
  #=> [[3, 4], [8, 5], [5, 6], [9, 7]]
```

The solution is now close at hand. We simply want to step through the elements of `before` and `after` until the first element of a pair is greater than `target #=> 7`.

At this point you're probably wondering if I've really simplified the problem at all. Be patient. I did it this way it order to use some Ruby methods. Firsly, let's combine `before` and `after` in a convenient way, using [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip). (You are reading the method definitions at the links, aren't you?)

Before doing so, it's convenient to make `before` and `after` the same length. One way to do that is as follows:

```
mx = [before.size, after.size].max
  #=> 4
if before.size < mx
  before.concat [[target, nil]]*(mx-before.size)
elsif after.size < mx
  after.concat [[target, nil]]*(mx-before.size)
end
before
  #=> [[4, 2], [8, 1], [2, 0], [7, nil]] 
after
  #=> [[3, 4], [8, 5], [5, 6], [9, 7]]
```

As you see, one element, `[7, nil]` was appended to `before`. I used the value of `target` for the first element, so it would never be selected.

We're now ready to `zip`:

```
pairs_of_pairs = before.zip(after)
  #=> [[[4, 2], [3, 4]], [[8, 1], [8, 5]],
  #    [[2, 0], [5, 6]], [[7, nil], [9, 7]]]
```

This array has four elements, the first being `[[4, 2], [3, 4]]`.

We can now use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to to obtain the index of the closest higher value:

```
p = pairs_of_pairs.find { |(b_val,_), (a_val,_)| [b_val, a_val].max > target }
  #=> [[8, 1], [8, 5]]
```

(Forget for the moment the way I've written the block variables.)

So `p` contains the first element in `pair_of_pairs` for which `[b_val, a_val].max > target` evaluates `true`. If there is no value in `arr` larger than `target`, `p` would equal `nil`.

Since `p` is not `nil`, all that's left is to determine which element of `p` contains a value higher than `target` and return the corresponding index. Because ties go to the left in `arr`, we check `before` first:

```
i = (p.first.first > target) ? p.first.last : p.last.last
  #=> 1
```

and the value is:

```
arr[i]
  #=> 8
```

Putting this all together, we can write:

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  target = arr[idx]
  pairs = arr.each_with_index.to_a
  before = (idx.zero? ? [] : pairs[0..idx-1]).reverse
  after  = pairs[idx+1..-1]
  mx = [before.size, after.size].max
  if before.size < mx
    before.concat [[target, nil]]*(mx-before.size)
  elsif after.size < mx
    after.concat [[target, nil]]*(mx-after.size)
  end
  p = before.zip(after).find { |(b_val,_), (a_val,_)|
    [b_val, a_val].max > target }
  p ? ((p.first.first > target) ? p.first.last : p.last.last) : nil
end

nearest_larger(arr, 3)
  #=> 1
nearest_larger(arr, 7)
  #=> nil
```

The last thing to clear up concerns the strange-looking block variables in:

```
p = pairs_of_pairs.find { |(b_val,_), (a_val,_)| [b_val, a_val].max > target }
```

`find` calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) to pass each element of `pairs_of_pairs` into the block. The first of those elements is `[[4, 2], [3, 4]]`. The assignment of values to the block uses both "parallel assignment" and "disambiguation":

```
(b_val,_), (a_val,_) = [[4, 2], [3, 4]]
  #=> [[4, 2], [3, 4]] 
b_val
  #=> 4 
a_val
  #=> 3 
_ #=> 3
```

I used underscore (a valid name for a local variable!) to draw attention to the fact that I'm not using it in the block calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_i`, which convert `nil` into `0` -

```
   def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
     i = idx
     until  arr[i].to_i > arr[idx].to_i || i.to_i == 0
      i -=1
     end
     left = arr[i]
     lefti = i
     i = idx
     puts arr[idx] #4
     puts arr[i] #4 (functions as nil in next line)
     until (arr[idx].to_i < arr[i].to_i) || (i.to_i == arr.length)
      i += 1
     end
     right = arr[i]
     righti = i
     puts righti
     if  righti.to_i == arr.length && lefti.to_i == 0
       return nil
     elsif right == left
       return lefti
     elsif right.to_i < left.to_i
      return lefti
     elsif right.to_i > left.to_i
      return righti
     else
      print "idk man"
     end
   end

   nearest_larger([2,8,4,3], 2)
```

Comment: If possible can you provide the explanation for why it was nil?